# A design pattern concerns

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've found something that very much resembles a design pattern. What I'm doing is creating an instance that is injected into multiple classess. It's by far a DI but what makes it distinct is that an instance is fed into multiple depending classess:

```
var instance = new ClassA();

var dep1 = new DependentFoo(instance);
var dep2 = new DependentBar(instance);
```

I've found it usefull for 2 example situations for now:

1. When making a modular code with multiple GUI modules. I feed an instance of current working data into different dependending classes, so for example when a "New file" is clicked the underlying data is cleared
2. In game development - when there are many different game modes - every needs a current terrain instance - for example two modes: road building mode and trees placement mode need to have the same instance, because they will work on the same data.

I could probably elaborate on this but my question is: is this a named pattern? I know that DI works by putting dependencies into class. But in my case it's going further - using that instance for multiple dependent classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific pattern, AFAIK. Providing a shared resource via DI is just an approach or technique. IoC frameworks would call this 'lifestyle' management.

Answer (score 1):

It's called object composition and isn't a "design pattern" per se but rather a way of structuring code so you cut down on repetition. People that strongly believe in exactly what you're doing expound on the principals of SOLID and DRY. These are good things if you're in an OO world. (They're also a good philosophy if you're in an FP world up, though DI is sometimes frowned upon.)

Comment: DI is also an object composition, maybe I shouldn't call DI a design pattern then?

Comment: BTW: DI is frowned upon because of people trying to do everything using it or prioritizing unit testing over the program core functionality. I'm also against that - unit tests will never solve any real problem.

Comment: @lukasz1985 Unit tests will solve many real problems. Actually unit tests solve real problems all the time, especially the ones that sit between a keyboard and a chair or at least prove that the code itself is not the problem.

Comment: The real world problems are the problems that are solved by the core programm functionality. The rest is the programmer as you said. If the programmer is not wise enough to figure out what he have done wrong, neither he fully understands the underlying system that he is creating, unit tests will never help enough. Programming gives the joy of understanding real life processess only if you really care about them. Tests are good - to prove that something is working. They can't prove anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the Observer pattern or the MVC pattern as these are what you seems to be going towards.

Comment: There is some resemblance to the MVC, true, especially if looking at the "dep1" and "dep2" in my example as the controllers and the "instance" as the "model".

Comment: Your instance does resembles a model, though I'm not quite sure that it's a fully fledged model yet. For a full MVC, the model would usually also implement and interacts with others through the observer pattern, and I'm also not quite sure you have fully split view and controllers yet. MVC is the standard design pattern used for writing UI, and it's also very common in games. I don't think what you have currently is MVC yet, but I think you're going towards MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Modern IoC containers know how to handle it.

It is called

1. [Lifestyles](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx#Standard_lifestyles%3a_the_less_common_ones_15) in Castle Windsor
2. [Scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) in Ninject
3. [Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx) in Unity

E.g. there is [Scoped Lifestyle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx#Scoped_7) in Castle Windsor. It ensures that resolved entities will be the same within the scope.

registration:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<MyScopedComponent>().LifestyleScoped())
```

usage:

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;

using (Container.BeginScope()) //extension method
{
    var one = Container.Resolve<MyScopedComponent>();
    var two = Container.Resolve<MyScopedComponent>();
    Assert.AreSame(one, two);

} // releases the instance
```

[Bound Lifestyle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx#Bound_8) is used in order to make sure that resolved entities will be the same within specific root/graph.